# A Non-Velocity Dependent 4-Vector Transformed as Velocity Dependent 4-Vector

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the following:

It is understandable that the Minkowski space Gauss' and Ampère-Maxwell equations in index notations
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\nu} F^{\mu\nu} = \mu_{0} J^{\mu}
\end{equation}
have the following form in a different inertial coordinate system
\begin{equation}
\partial'_{\nu} F'^{\mu\nu} = \mu_{0} J'^{\mu}.
\end{equation}
This is trivial, because it follows from Galileo's Principle of Relativity.

The problem arises when the 4-vector $J$ in one of the inertial systems is represented as $J'$ in the other inertial system by the rule involving the use of the Lorentz transformation matrix $\Lambda$ to represent in another inertial system the 4-vector $\textbf{a} = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$
\begin{equation}
\textbf{a}' = \Lambda \textbf{a},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
    \beta       & -\frac{\beta v}{c}  & 0  & 0 \\
    -\frac{\beta v}{c}       & \beta & 0 & 0 \\
    0      & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0      & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $\beta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$.

From the above, it seems obvious that a 4-vector $\textbf{a} = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$, which is not a function of velocity $v$, is represented in another inertial system as a velocity dependent vector $\textbf{a}' = \Lambda \textbf{a}$. How is this not in violation of the Principle of Relativity?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "velocity-dependent vector". Of course the relation between the elements of $a'$ and $a$ depends on the relative velocity $v$ of the frames -- how could it not? Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: I find the question confusing for a couple reasons.  How does Galilean relativity play into general covariance?  Maxwell's equations are NOT invariant under Galilean transforms, which is precisely how special relativity arises.